# Is there a way to detect regular expression support in a htaccess file?

Tags: apache-http-server, regex, mod-rewrite

I use to following rewrite rule to pass the whole url to an php script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?rewriteUrl=$1 [QSA,L]
```

On some servers, I have to use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewriteUrl=$1 [QSA,L]
```

instead (the `?` is missing).

Is there a way to make the server handle this automatically? In form of a fallback/try-catch or something like this?

Comment: I can't say I understand your question or the point of having the `?` in the expression. For information on regular expression usage in mod_rewrite, please see the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the different version numbers between the two servers, use [mod_version](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_version.html#ifversion) to do this. For instance, if 2.3+ uses the `?`:

```
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?rewriteUrl=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfVersion>

<IfVersion < 2.3>
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewriteUrl=$1 [QSA,L]        
</IfVersion>
```

Use [ServerSignature](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serversignature) to have the version info sent to the client.